# MingW reporting missing .dll file in Netbeans + Qt

Tags: c++, qt, netbeans, mingw

I installed Netbeans 7.0.1 and the Qt SDK and set it up as per the instructions on [here](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/qt-applications.html). The code builds nicely but when I press run I get the following error:

```
The application failed with exit code -1073741515 (0xc0000135). 
This could indicate that no required .dll was found in the PATH. 
Please try to start the following command from the command shell (cmd.exe). 
This may give some additional information. 

"C:\..." //file location 

RUN FAILED (exit value -1,073,741,515, total time: 35ms)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated 
-Tamas

Comment: Have you added directory with dll's installed by QtSDK to your PATH?

Comment: @maciek **how would I be able to do that? **  



I followed this instructions after downloading...
  
1. In the NetBeans IDE, select Tools > Options > C/C++ to open the C/C++ properties.  
2. Click Add in the Tool Collections area.  
3. Specify the Qt MinGW installation's bin directory as the tool collection's Base Directory (for example, c:\Qt\2010.02.1\mingw\bin)  
4. Set the Tool Collection Name to MinGW_Qt and click OK, then click OK in the Options dialog box.

Comment: for win xp: right click on My Computer, Properties, tab: Advanced, Environment Variables

Comment: @maciek what should I change it too?

Comment: You should check if it contains path to folder, where dll files from QtSDK are placed. Important: do not delete anything from there!

Comment: @maciek it is not there, how would I add it?

Comment: 1st google link: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you need some dlls to run the executable, so you have to put them on the local directory in order to run it, and when you finish coding you will have to find a way to make them available to final user, here is a little tutorial made for qt creator that explains it very good, just have in mind that clicking the run button in netbeans it's almost the same than double clicking the executable in the `dist/release` or `dist/debug` folder https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X1BsPQue5-k

Answer (score 0):

You can place the required DLL's in your `dist` folder (`dist/debug/...` or `dist/release/...`, where your exe is), e.g.:

- QtCore4.dll
- QtCored4.dll
- QtGui4Qt
- Guid4.dll

(You can take them from `<Path to Qt>/bin`.

Comment: You dont need both: qtcore and qtcored (same with qtgui).