# Qt 4.8.4 mingw (gcc 4.7) can compile but cannot run

Tags: qt, mingw

i am new to Qt.
i am using Wnndows 8 with MinGW (gcc 4.7.2)
i have installed QtLibrary 4.8.4(the official site says Qt 4.84 should work with mingw 4.4)
After modified Windows environment variables, i installed Qt Creator 2.6 and setted the kit as well.

now i can compile the example program, but cannot run it, the error message I got is

Starting D:\usr\bin\Qt4\examples\opengl\2dpainting-build-Kit_3_14-Debug\debug\2dpainting.exe...
The program has unexpectedly finished.
D:\usr\bin\Qt4\examples\opengl\2dpainting-build-Kit_3_14-Debug\debug\2dpainting.exe exited with code -1073741502

i met the same problem with Qt 5.0.1 + MinGw 4.7.2 too.
i guess there is something wrong with "opengl", but don't know how to fix it. 
please help.

Comment: Use dependency walker to see if any dlls are missing.

Comment: If you fixed the problem yourself you should add an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to place all required dlls into the directory where your exe is (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252583/mingw-reporting-missing-dll-file-in-netbeans-qt/13347157#13347157)).
Also make shure; if you are compilung in *Debug* you need eg. QtCore**d**4.dll, but in *release* QtCore4.dll.

Comment: i copied QtCore4.dll QtCored4.dll QtGuid.dll QtGuid.dll  form /Qt/bin/  to the destination dir as suggested <a href = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252583/mingw-reporting-missing-dll-file-in-netbeans-qt?answertab=active#tab-top"> there </a> but the problem remained.

Comment: Ok, next run your program in debug an check where it chrashes. if you get a `SIGSEV` or similar see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13962857/qt-application-segmentation-fault-with-mingw-4-7-2

Comment: i downloaded MinGW4.4 and changed the Qt settings, now it works fine. it seems that required gcc version cannot be replace with another one. Thanks for your advise.

Comment: For Qt 4.x you need MinGW 4.4 - everything else is not working. But if my answer solved your problem, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

It all about x32 and x64 architectures,
If you compile cpp files in x64 mode and then link them with x32 qt the problem will occur.
try using the appropriate versions of windows and qt(both x32 or both x64)